# How is "Base Damage" calculated and what affects it?

Tags: heroes-of-newerth

Last night I was playing an "All-Mid" game and used artillery for the first time. His LRM (long range missiles) skill does 15 damage + 35% of "Base" weapon damage with each shot.

My question arose as the result of me wondering what items would be synergistic with the LRM skill for boosting base damage. Is base damage a derivative of your primary stat?  Do items with +X damage count as "Base"?

A sub-question: Is there a good website/forum for Heroes of Newerth that breaks down and explains all intricacies of the game mechanics (like "what orb effects stack").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base damage is simply your hero's starting damage (This is your damage done at level one with no items, minus your primary statistic), plus any damage derived from your primary statistic.

Say you're playing `Artillery`, and your items include a `Savage Mace` and `Steamboots`, which are cycled to agility.

Your `Savage Mace` gives you only damage (ignoring the proc).
Your `Steamboots` give you ten agility, which in turn provides ten base damage.
The Savage Mace has no impact on the damage done by your `LRM` because it does not affect base damage, whereas your `Steamboots` will.

So essentially, base damage is your total damage before damage bonuses.

The Heroes of Newerth forums have dozens of pages devoted to such discussion, but the most important two are:

- http://forums.heroesofnewerth.com/forumdisplay.php?22-Mechanics
- http://forums.heroesofnewerth.com/wiki/index.php/Category:Mechanics

And to answer the orb question, orbs are known as attack modifiers. If it is listed as an 'attack modifier', it will not stack with other attack modifiers. Note however that items such as `Nullfire Blade` and `Thunderclaw/Charged Hammer` are not attack modifiers, but `Mana Combustion` and `Lightning` modifiers, respectively.

Comment: Nullfire is not an attack modifier?  (I had assumed it was)...  I assume that Thunderclaw & Charged Hammer were not attack modifiers (because 1. they are sold in the "Combative Recipe" shop and 2. they are triggered abilities, rather than 100% active passives.)